# InvalidJSONprimitive:ABC Ajax call in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

my script

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
             var ABC = 'TEST';
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod"  ,
                 data: "{ EmailAddress : ABC }",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (msg) {
                     alert(msg);
                     $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                 }
             })
             return false;
         });
     });
     </script>
```

Code behind method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod(string EmailAddress)
{
    return EmailAddress ;
}

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click" />
<br /><br />
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

at button click it give me **InvalidJSONprimitive:ABC** this error can any body tell what i m doing wron.

Comment: `"{ EmailAddress : ABC }"` isn't valid JSON, and you aren't passing the value of ABC into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly states, the JSON that you're sending to the server is invalid.
String literals in JSON must be quoted.

You should call `JSON.stringify({ EmailAddress: ABC })` to build a JSON string from a Javascript object expression.